# repeat numbers in shell script

Tags: shell

I have numbers 1-12 and letters a,b,c,d.

abcd letters should repeat for every 4 numbers like the below output, thanks

expecting output like

```
1-a
2-b
3-c
4-d
5-a
6-b
7-c
8-d
9-a
10-b
11-c
12-c
```

I have tried with for loop but it didn't work.

```
for i in {1..12}; do for x in a b c d ; do echo "$i $x"; done; done
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do the file contents look like **exactly**? If you want to join two lists you don't want recursive loops. You want a single loop (if that even).

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: for x in `cat ldevs`; do for i in `cat id`; do echo "device $x lunid $i"; done; done

ldevs file have `1 2 3 4 5 6` and id file have `a b c d e f`.

Comment: You should really edit the question and include the code for your loop and a sample of the files.

Comment: Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @Shaggy true. Sorry abt that. New to this site. Trying to figure out if there's a way to upload

Comment: Copy and paste. Then, highlight the data and press Ctrl-K to make it readable.

Comment: @Govardhan The code in your last comment is not Perl...is there any Perl code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 4):

Use paste command like:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 10 lines of input in each file and you want 10 lines of output, so there should only be one loop.

1. While true,

   1. Read a line from one file.
   2. If reached EOF,

      1. Exit loop.
   3. Read a line from the other file.
   4. Print the combined lines.